# SSRS - Using IF Condition in a Dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssis, ssrs-tablix

I have a table structure in place. But, the data I push into this data varies depending upon a input

```
Input A - Query X 

Input B - Query Y
```

In order to achieve this, I was thinking, I will put in a IF Condition in the dataset and have it direct to "Query X" or "Query Y" based on the "Input".

I tried this,

```
IF(Input=='Hello')
(
...
)
```

But, this threw an error. Can you help me on how to proceed here? Is there a better way I can achieve my req.?

Comment: Is creating Stored Procedures an option in your environment?

Comment: Nope. I cannot do that.

Comment: I've posted an answer for you.  I'd really recommend against using an IF statement if any other solutions will fit the bill - you're not going to end up with a good execution, as "IF" is going to cause a lot of recompiles, so performance is going to suffer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise against the IF statement for performance reasons, but if you must, the syntax in SQL is:

```
if ( 'blah' = 'blah' )
begin
    --do stuff
end
```

Some other options you might consider, instead of an IF:

- Use Stored Procedures, have a "master" sproc called by the report, which then executes the appropriate sproc based off the parameters it receives.
- UNION ALL your potential queries together, and include a line in the WHERE clause to make only the query you want the results from return any rows.
- If the differences in your queries are simple enough, perhaps you can just use CASE statements to apply the correct logic?